# How can I define a method's return class dynamically in C# without the 'dynamic' keyword?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, types

I have several classes inherited from "scriptable object" Unity - "Item" is the main class, from which the others are inherited: "Tool", "Weapon", "Food" and several others. I have access to each instance of the class only through the dictionary (Example:
`Dictionary <string, Tool> toolsDatabase;  Dictionary <string, Weapon> weaponsDatabase;  Dictionary <string, Food> foodsDatabase");`
I can get the desired item through its name (string) and since the key data type of all dictionaries is the same, I can't do method overloading. Therefore, at runtime, the class must be defined and it must return, but I don't know how to do it without dynamic typing.
I thought it would be possible to return multiple instances of classes simultaneously via tuple, but then you would have to create an additional check for each method call, which when the code grows, will cause code support difficulties. And dynamic type as I understand it can cause decrease performance if you use it often.

Here's a little bit of code. Maybe I really didn't ask the right question for C#. In brief, the task is to get different classes from several dictionaries storing different classes in values using one keyword and one method.
private static Dictionary<string, Item> items;

```
    public static Dictionary<string, Item> Items => items;
    private static Dictionary<string, Tool> tools;
    public static Dictionary<string, Tool> Tools => tools;
    private static Dictionary<string, Weapon> weapons;
    public static Dictionary<string, Weapon> Weapons => weapons;

    [SerializeField] private List<Item> itemsDatabase = new List<Item>();
    [SerializeField] private List<Tool> toolsDatabase = new List<Tool>();
    [SerializeField] private List<Weapon> weaponsDatabase = new List<Weapon>();

    public Item GetItem(string itemName)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Key == itemName)
            {
                return item.Value;
            }
        }
        foreach (var tool in tools)
        {
            if (tool.Key == itemName)
            {
                return tool.Value;
            }
        }
        foreach (var weapon in weapons)
        {
            if (weapon.Key == itemName)
            {
                return weapon.Value;
            }
        }
        return new Item();
    }
```

Comment: Would [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) meet your needs ?

Comment: Please show some code. You could perhaps use a `Tool GetTool(string name)` but it's not clear from your description whether that would suffice.

Comment: _"How can I define a method's return class dynamically"_ - you shouldn't actually _want_ to. Except you need something like discriminated unions, which are not supported (yet) but workaround libs exist.

Comment: Or indeed Generics, although I am not sure it will be what you mean: `TItem Get<TItem>(string key) where TItem: Item` - this still needs you to know the Type at compiletime.

Comment: If `dynamic` is the answer, you should think long and hard if you are asking the right question. The most natural way should be a `GetTool` method as CodeCaster suggest. I would also suggest reading Eric Lipperts [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) series, it discusses the difficulty in using the type system to represent concepts in the game.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a common interface for `Tool`, `Weapon`, and `Food`. But it's hard to tell, because you need to show us more code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a single dictionary

```cs
Dictionary<string, Item> itemsDatabase;
```

Then you have the choice to look up for any type of item with a given key, or you can use this method with a generic type parameter:

```cs
private bool TryGetItem<T>(string key, out T t)
    where T : Item
{
    if (itemsDatabase.TryGetValue(key, out Item item) && item is T specificItem) {
        t = specificItem;
        return true;
    }
    t = null;
    return false;
}
```

Usage

```cs
if (TryGetItem<Food>("apple", out Food apple)) {
    // ...
}
```

This can be simplified a bit by either specifying only the type of the `out` parameter or only the generic type parameter and letting the C# compiler inferring the other one:

```cs
if (TryGetItem("apple", out Food apple)) {

}

// OR

if (TryGetItem<Food>("apple", out var apple)) {

}
```

or you can switch on the type like this

```cs
if (itemsDatabase.TryGetValue("someKey", out Item item)) {
    switch (item) {
        case Tool tool:
            tool.Apply();
            break;
        case Weapon weapon:
            weapon.Attack();
            break;
        case Food food:
            food.Eat();
            break;
    }
}
```

In some cases, you can also use [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) to avoid a type test. Example: Instead of having distinct methods for each item type like `Apply`, `Attack` and `Eat` as shown above, add an abstract method `Use` in the abstract base class `Item`. Each kind of item then adds its own implementation.

```cs
if (itemsDatabase.TryGetValue("someKey", out Item item)) {
    item.Use(); // Tools are applied, weapons attack and food is eaten.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. But it turns out to be the same problem as before. Since I have to exactly return an instance of a particular class, but it's the instance with the "Item" class that will be returned. In this case, I will have to do an explicit type conversion to return, for example, to the original "Tool" class and always do some additional checks when calling such a method.

Comment: Well, either you know that you are looking for a tool, then you can use my `TryGetItem` method, otherwise you will have to do a type check, unless you use polymorphy. Ill'add an example.